# Graph - Path from s to t with minimal individual edge length

Tags: algorithm, graph

I was wondering if Dijkstra's algorithm can be modified to find the path between two nodes where the max of all the edge lengths in the path is smallest.

ie it would prefer a path of edges length 1,3,5,9 over a path of a single edge length 10 because max(1,3,5,9) < max(10)

Comment: [Minimum Spanning Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree) is better than Dijstra to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this can be done using Dijkstra's algorithm

Hint: At each node u, store the smallest weight w, so that there exists a path through visited vertices from s to u whose max weight is w. Think of modifying the relaxation condition upon visiting a new vertex to satisfy the above condition.

Answer (score 0):

Remember when d(u) is updated by d(v)+c(u,v)? Now instead of that you just update d(u) by max(d(v),c(u,v)) instead.

Another solution is to do binary search for the result. For a given upper bound, you can remove edges violating that upper bound, then DFS/BFS to check if there is still a path between two nodes s & t. So now you can try different upper bound to find the tightest one with binary search.